# why is my tabbar gray on first start

Tags: objective-c, ios4, ios-simulator

hi 
i have the following problem.
since today when my app launches the tabbar is gray ([image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EKx3T.png)) !.

as soon as i change the view (tab a cell)
and go back, the tabbar is black as it should be ([image](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/14257606/Screenshot_2.png)) !!

why could that be ?
i do not have any idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

alright I figured out what went wrong.
I have a tab detection window in front of everything
and as soon as I set the opacity down to 0% the tab bar
was black again.
thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

The only way i see that that could happen is that you have changed the color of the tabbar manually to gray using code but i guess with you thats not the case here.
to solve the problem, try resetting the "bottom bar" attribute to "tabbar"
hope it works out...

Comment: bottom bar is set to tabbar ;(